# Count the total times value based on name on google spreadsheet

Tags: conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am creating a sheet that will automatically count the time spent from the log file.
I was able to separate the name, action, date and time automatically. I also able to get the time differences. However, since the name maybe repeated more than once, I couldn't find away to automatically count the total time for each name.
On the screenshot the green cells is what I wish to be automated. So it will count the total time for the similar name.

[image: spreadsheet on google sheet. green cell showing the expected automation]

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `G2` and apply to the column

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A2,A2,F$2:F2)
```